# Python - darknetpy object detection from image url instead of local file location

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I have created a custom yolo object detection and trying to use the same using the darknet python wrapper `darknetpy`. Below is my code

```
from darknetpy.detector import Detector

detector = Detector('data/obj.data',
                    'cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg',
                    'weights/yolov3_custom_last.weights')


image_loc = 'filepath/image.jpg'
boxes = detector.detect(image_loc)
```

this returns the coordinates of the objects with class on confidence correctly. However, i want to perform the detection on an image URL from web for which i tried to download the image using `requests` and `PIL` and pass the image object to detector as below

```
import requests
from PIL import Image as PILImage
from darknetpy.detector import Detector


detector = Detector('data/obj.data',
                    'cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg',
                    'weights/yolov3_custom_last.weights')

url = 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81LtUCz2wYL._UY879_.jpg'
response = requests.get(url)
image_loc = PILImage.open(BytesIO(response.content))
boxes = detector.detect(image_loc)
```

however this is throwing me an error as i am passing an image object instead of the local image location. 
I know that this can be fixed by saving the image object to local as a jpg or png file and use the location, instead is there any other solution to darknetpy wherein i can pass the image object instead of the image location from local

Answer (score 1):

darknetpy only accepts an image path and does not provide a method for passing in an image as an object.

To achieve this functionality; you can clone the repository https://github.com/danielgatis/darknetpy and implement the changes.

It looks like the detect() function is contained in [/src/lib.rs](https://github.com/danielgatis/darknetpy/blob/master/src/lib.rs), It's implemented using [rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/).

```
fn detect(
    &self,
    img_path: String,
    thresh: Option<f32>,
    hier_thresh: Option<f32>,
    nms: Option<f32>,
) -> PyObject {
    // ... [HIDDEN]

    let image = unsafe { load_image_color(CString::new(img_path).expect("invalid img_path").into_raw(), 0, 0) };
    let sized = unsafe { letterbox_image(image, (*self.network).w, (*self.network).h) };

    unsafe { network_predict(self.network, sized.data) };

    let num_ptr = &mut 0 as *mut i32;
    let boxes = unsafe {
        get_network_boxes(
            self.network,
            image.w,
            image.h,
            thresh,
            hier_thresh,
            0 as *mut i32,
            0,
            num_ptr,
        )
    };
    // ... [HIDDEN]
```

The *img_path* is converted to *image*.Afterwards the *img_path* is no longer consumed. Therefore in custom code, create a new function that either handles the image conversion or passes in an image. I believe the image is a struct https://nebgnahz.github.io/darknet-rs/darknet/ffi/struct.image.html

To illustrate, I've created a method that passes in an image in directly:

```
fn detect_image(
    &self,
    image: image,
    thresh: Option<f32>,
    hier_thresh: Option<f32>,
    nms: Option<f32>,
) -> PyObject {
    // ... [HIDDEN]
    let sized = unsafe { letterbox_image(image, (*self.network).w, (*self.network).h) };

    unsafe { network_predict(self.network, sized.data) };

    let num_ptr = &mut 0 as *mut i32;
    let boxes = unsafe {
        get_network_boxes(
            self.network,
            image.w,
            image.h,
            thresh,
            hier_thresh,
            0 as *mut i32,
            0,
            num_ptr,
        )
    };
    // ... [HIDDEN]
```

Also you should be able to achieve the same results with **darknet** (not to be confused with **darknetpy**). More details can be found on https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/289

Comment: I am sorry, i did not get this. Could you please explain this?

Comment: Sorry I've updated the answer with more details. I got darknetpy  mixed up with darknet. However the same principle applies you'll need to write custom code to either transform or supply the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the images locally and after detection remove the locally saved image file.

```
img_data = session.get(src).content
f_name = 'image_name.jpg'
with open(f_name, 'wb') as handler:
  handler.write(img_data)
img = cv2.imread('image_name.jpg', 0)
#After Detecting Delete te image
os.remove("image_name.jpg")
```

Comment: I donot want to use the locally saved image, that was my primary concern. We are adding more complexities here i guess.  i was wondering if there was any option to directly use the image object